# Joi conditional .required()

Tags: javascript, joi

I have a function that returns a Joi schema. The string in that schema can either be required or optional.

Here is my function:

```js
function myString(required) {
  const schema = Joi.string();

  if (required) schema.required();

  return schema;
}
```

Calling `myString(true)` does not apply `.required()`. However, the string is required if my function is defined as:

```js
function myString() {
  const schema = Joi.string().required();

  return schema;
}
```

I wanted a function to apply that conditional `.required()` (and other validations) so I don't waste time writing `Joi.string()` or `Joi.string().required()` everywhere.
So, the following doesn't fit my need:

```js
function myString(required) {
  return required ? Joi.string().required() : Joi.string();
}
```

Why is my first function not working? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`joi` function return `this` instance you need to store that to variable. it's `builder`

```js
function myString(required) {
  let schema = Joi.string();

  if (required) {
    schema = schema.required();
  }

  return schema;
}
```

Comment: Ah right! Thanks a lot!!